# Modelling time between points using only delta inputs

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to create a graphing function to model the time a vehicle will take to move a certain distance along a predetermined route. Obviously the ideal would be to have multiple input graphs of percentage along the route and time from start to load in and run something like KRLS over it to predict future numbers (I'd then want to switch this into a 3d graph by adding a time of day dimension so as to account for differences in journey time at different times).

However, for the input I only have partial data which contains position along the route at a particular timestamp (which is not based on when it started). Using 2 of these data points (which may be very close eg 10 seconds or very far apart eg 30 minutes) I can figure out a differential eg to get from 10% to 20% along the route took 5 minutes. My initial thought with this approach would be to feed these deltas into a function from which a differential graph would be created. Then using this graph I can integrate between different points to figure out the time that it would take to get between the two. However my questions with this approach are:

- How to integrate between points in the graph once created?
- How to handle the big differences of time period covered by each differential input (ie a differential over a 30 minute time window should be handled differently from that over a 10 second window)

Or is there any better way to create a graph/kernel function when only the deltas not absolute points are available?

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully appreciate the difficulty of this problem---but it sounds like something you could do with regression.

Input features/predictor variables are the speed (%of the route covered per second), time of day, window width, and anything else you think is important. Output/response variable is the time required to complete the journey. You could start with linear regression, and add in non-linearities if it becomes necessary.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think that this will work there are a number of rules it would be good to encode for example time will always increase with distance, the more data points the more accurate the route will be. It's basically a very simple 2d graph I'm wanting (at the moment). By adding all the other variables it might start trying to predict arrival time from a 10 second sample which would be wildly inaccurate..

Comment: None of those points mean you can't use simple regression---"time will always increase with distance" just means the coefficient for distance is positive, for example. If you're sure the graph is what you want then by all means pursue it, I'm the wrong person to help you with that approach!